# How to get last day of a month from a given date?

Tags: oracle, plsql

For example, the given date is ***04/04/1924*** and I want to find out the last day of February of the year 1924.

I came up with the add_month but it seems not flexible if I have different given month from data source

Any good ideas ?

Comment: 04/04/1924 --> here 04 represents april not February do you want 2 months back last day

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Oracle has a [`last_day()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions077.htm) function:

```
SELECT LAST_DAY(to_date('04/04/1924','MM/DD/YYYY')) from dual;

SELECT LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(to_date('04/04/1924','MM/DD/YYYY'), -1)) from dual;

SELECT LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(to_date('04/04/1924','MM/DD/YYYY'), -2)) from dual;
```

Results:

```
April, 30 1924 00:00:00+0000

March, 31 1924 00:00:00+0000

February, 29 1924 00:00:00+0000
```

Use [`Add_Months()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions004.htm) on your date to get the appropriate month, and then apply [`last_day()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions077.htm).

Comment: It will do, yes. It'll [work with a fair few other things as well](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/8840), it's really confusing though... and it's partially an accident that it works. Oracle's internals, IMHO, strip out too much data from the date-format. It's tripped me up on occasion; annoyingly. Please feel free to rollback if you want :-).

Answer (score 3):

query inpl sql to get first day and last day of the month :

first day :

```
select to_date(to_char(LAST_DAY(sysdate),'YYYYMM'),'YYYYMM')  from dual;
```

Last day:

```
select LAST_DAY(to_date(to_char((sysdate),'YYYYMM'),'YYYYMM'))  from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will show you the last day of month

```
SELECT  Max(LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -2)) + level)
FROM    dual
CONNECT BY
    level <= LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -1)) - LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -2))
```

you can replace system date what ever date you want with to_date('04/04/1924','MM-DD-YYYY')

```
SELECT  Max(LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(to_date('04/04/1924','MM-DD-YYYY'), -2)) + level)
FROM    dual
CONNECT BY
    level <= LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(to_date('04/04/1924','MM-DD-YYYY'), -1)) - LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(to_date('04/04/1924','MM-DD-YYYY'), -2))
```

or simply

```
select LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(to_date('04/04/1924','MM-DD-YYYY'), -2)) from dual;
```

Comment: i'm not seen. i'm in edit mode absolutely your thing is right. i give +1 to your answer

Answer (score 0):

to get the selected month and year last day:

SELECT TO_CHAR(LAST_DAY(TO_DATE(:X_THE_MONTH ||'/01/' || :X_THE_YEAR,'MM/DD/YYYY')), 'dd') FROM DUAL

Answer (score 0):

if you want know if your date is final mount

```
SELECT
case when
TO_DATE('19240430','YYYYMMDD') = LAST_DAY(TO_DATE('04/04/1924','MM/DD/YYYY'))
THEN 1 ELSE 0 END LAST_MOUNTH_DAY FROM DUAL
```

Answer (score 0):

Get First and Last Date of the Month
Just change the Month digit to get the first and last date of the month

```
 select
  to_date('01/'|| '07/' || to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY'), 'dd/mm/yyyy') first,
  last_day(to_date('01/'|| '07/' || to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY'), 'dd/mm/yyyy')) last
  from  dual
```

Result:

```
first         last
-------------------------- 
01/02/2017  28/02/2017
```

Answer (score 0):

the simple way to do is :

```
select first_name , last_day(hire_date) from employees;
```

i am using HR schema...  you can get the last day of the mentioned month.