# returning last day of the month

Tags: mysql, sql, plsql, reportbuilder3.0

```
function lastdayinmonthFormula return Number is

begin
  last_day(to_date(to_char(lpad(:month,2,'0')||:year),'ddmmyyyy'));
end;
```

How to return date to field.
I am getting error like,

> last_day is not procedure or is undefined.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get last day of a month from a given date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15445216/how-to-get-last-day-of-a-month-from-a-given-date)

Comment: last_day function is ok but i dont knoq how to return that date to display

Comment: PL/SQL already has a `last_day` function.

Comment: problem was that this functions returns number instead date

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE())+1,0))
```

or check link
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/08/18/sql-server-find-last-day-of-any-month-current-previous-next/

Comment: last_day function is ok but i dont knoq how to return that date to display

Answer (score 0):

Answer is :

function lastdayinmonthFormula return Number is
it should return Date not number.